# Mandrill API Java unit tests

Tags: java, mailchimp, mandrill

We are used MandrillApp in production server without autotesting. How to I can mocking mandriil api call for unit test, without real sending message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mandrill, go to SMTP & API Credentials on your main menu.

Click "+ New API Key"

Give it a description (something like TEST KEY is good).

Check the "Test Key" check-box.

Click the "Create API Key" button.

You will create a new API key in your list.  It's a ~22 digit key just like your main API key.

Use this key instead of your main API key in any test calls and the message(s) will not be sent.

To observe the simulated results in Mandrill, go to your account menu and turn on "Test Mode".  You will then be able to see all the incoming test API calls.